# Android Button with two images and Text

Tags: android, xml, button

I am trying to build the android app and need to build a button with two images and some text .

here is the example image :

[image]

how can i build this button in android ? any help would be appreciated .

Comment: have you tried drawable attribute of the button 'android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"'

Comment: you could also use a linear layout (or others) that acts and looks like a button. That contains image, text, image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
     <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/video_camera"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow"
        android:text="See a Medical\nDoctor Now"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is some code to get you started. Lets begin with the background. If that background is not provided to you and you have to create it yourself, lets create a custom_button_bg.xml file and add to your drawable folder.

custom_button_bg.xml Note: that I am just doing the basic shape for you. Adjust shadow and corner radius as you wish

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/teal"
        android:startColor="@color/teal"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/shadow"/>
</shape>
```

Now simply create your layout, something like below. Just replace the src and labels.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_rounded_white_button">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_video_cam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/video_cam"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_video_cam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="See a Medical \nDoctor Now"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Two Options:

You can utilize `setBackgroundDrawable()` on your `Button` to set the background of the button to an image with the icons you want, then your text will appear above the background.

Or you could try and utilize `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourimage"` and/or `android:drawableRight="@drawable/yourimage"` in your XML file nested in your `Button`.

[HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableRight) you can find more information on drawableRight/Left

Answer (score 0):

**I face to same problem in my case below code worked ;)**

```
            android:layout_width="370dp"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flag_us_little"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow"
            android:text="English language"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```

**Cheers!**

Answer (score -1):

Three steps:

1. Took a screenshot of the image you provided.
2. Places the screenshot in the drawable project of my folder and named it "background"
3. in my layout xml file. set the image as the button background:

   ```
   <Button
   android:layout_width="165dp"
   android:layout_height="35dp"
   android:background="@drawable/background"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:id="@+id/button"
   android:paddingTop="2sp"
   android:drawablePadding="-1sp"
    ></Button>
   ```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Please do not use images to post code. Also, this is a really bad implementation. The reason being, it will not scale for DPI and/or screen sizes.

Comment: I don't generally do that but for some reason I am not able to post the button xml layout as code for my answer probably because <></> is conflicting with the SO's editor. Feel free to post a better implementation. We are all here to learn from better.

Comment: removed downvote since answer better formatted. See @portfoliobuilder answer for how i would do it. The text and layout scales better for all DPIs, and the images can be provided with a set of drawables, or vectors. People are also hinting at setting left and right drawables. I have never tried setting both, didnt think it was possible. But if it is, its an excellent answer.